What are the advantages and disadvantages of signing international protocols?
I notice that only about 150 nations, out of 193 UN member states, have signed e.g. the Convention relating to the
Status of Refugees. What are the disadvantages to a nation to sign an international convention such as this and others? For that matter, what are the advantages too?
My question uses this particular document as an example, but the question pertains to all international conventions.

A lot is going to depend on what is being signed.

Most treaties create bilateral obligations, i.e. quid-pro-quo. However the kind you link to, like most IHL does not. So, if you want to focus on that kind in particular, you should be a bit more explicit.

Thanks. I would appreciate answers that address all kinds of treaties, I'm asking because I'd like to learn about the consequences as a whole. Thank you.

The problem is treaties vary a lot depending on what is being done so it could be just makes you look good or it could put a lot of restrictions on you. Both of those types will give a very different answer.

To nit pick, a "protocol" and a "treaty" or "convention" are not necessary the same thing, but I think that the body text of the question makes the intent clear enough, albeit, awfully broad and vague.

In general there are probably more advantages associated with negotiating such a treaty as opposed to passively signing one that others have created. It's an excellent opportunity to gain advantage over others by making up rules that have that effect. For example, carbon intensity (so a few hours of lawyer fees is equivalent to a 40' sea shipment container full of goods) vs. per capita carbon or per capita domestic consumption.

If a country signs a treaty it will generally be bound as a matter of domestic law in its own courts to obey that treaty. This could be a positive thing, because it may entrench the requirements of the treaty beyond meddling in future domestic politics, but it also limits the ability of current and future governments to act as they wish.
The benefit is that other countries will be similarly bound. For example, the Convention relating to the Status of Refugees, may force the burden of refugees to be shared among signatory nations in the face of a burden that might otherwise fall only on the nation in question.
Often multilateral treaties afford preferential treatment in their subject-matter area to other signatories of it and their nationals and companies.
Ultimately, it is a quasi-contractual bargain that has to be evaluated on a case by case basis. Many treaties are proposed and never come into force because the terms aren't sufficiently mutually beneficial. The treaties that do come into force usually provide some sort of mutual benefit or uphold some widely held norm.
For example, international copyright treaties benefit authors in the signatory country worldwide with improved global protection of their copyrights, at the cost of having to honor the copyrights of foreign authors. And, if your country buys into the general concept of copyright protection, the benefits will be seen as great and the obligations arising from it will seem fair.

Quasi-contractual bargain really sits at odds with the frequent refrain here that the notion of international law is very different from domestic law, esp given the lack of enforcement mechanism.  Furthermore, the Refugee Convention can hardly be expected to do much to equalize burdens when the EU itself struggles to gets its own member states to do so, with way more political leverage.  I am not necessarily against signing these treaties, in fact I am mostly in favor.  But this is an entirely too rose-tinted take.  Copyright/IP treaties are nowhere as challenged as others, in rich countries

@ItalianPhilosopher The signing of a treaty will often, either directly, or through enactment of legislation to carry out the obligations of the treaty, create a domestic law legal obligation that can be enforced in the signing party's courts by people who have standing to do so because they suffer a personalized injury from the treaty being disregarded. Obviously, it would depend on the nature of the treaty, however. And treaties are signed because the signing parties think that there is some benefit to doing so. Another possible benefit is good PR in the international community.

There is also the difference between signing and ratifying a treaty (https://ask.un.org/faq/14594), where you sometimes see long delays between a government signing a treaty at a conference, and that country then actually ratifying it by signing it into legislation in that country. Often this has to do with internal politics where one party (the government) thinks that X is a super important thing, but other parties in their parliament think that it is bad or at least not worth the commitment, and then they have to negotiate an agreement before an actual law can be made.

@Frodyne Depending on local constitutional arrangements, signing a treaty, ratifying a treaty and creating legislation to turn it into law can even be separate steps, each with politics attached.

One very general advantage that hasn't been mentioned is that when ratifying a treaty like this one, you can make reservation to preemptively guide its interpretation. As an example of a reservation that has been extensively discussed is Turkey's geographical limitation to the definition of a refugee, which excludes all people who became refugees as a results of events occurring outside of Europe.
That's especially relevant for human rights law and things that may be considered part of jus cogens where not ratifying the treaty is not enough to avoid obligations like “non-refoulement” or a bad reputation if you ignore them.

For the same reason countries will often choose to defend themselves in international court, even where the decision is non binding. The UK lost the Diego Garcia case under conservatives and chose to ignore it but then Liberals got elected and gave it up to Mauritius. The Conservatives knew that might happen so chose to at least try and defend themselves in court rather than demonstratively ignoring the proceedings.

Technically speaking that wasn't a reservation because the choice was baked into the treaty text itself. "(the 1951 Convention) was limited by terms of both geography and time. Article 1(B) of the 1951 Convention allowed the signatory parties the possibility of accepting “events occurring before 1 January 1951” as referring to either “events occurring in Europe before 1 January 1951” or “to events occurring anywhere in the world before 1 January 1951”". The subsequent  1967 Protocol then did the same, allowing the initial choice to be kept "as per Article 1(3)".

TL;DR:
Disadvantage:  You can be held accountable for the provisions of the treaty.
Advantage: You can hold others accountable for the provisions of the treaty.

Classical examples might include bans on particularly insidious warfare practices, bans on weaponry that can cause widespread, indiscriminate and/or lasting damage to people or the environment, proposals that boost the bare minimum of human rights, disarmament in general, refrains to use a particularly dangerous or harmful technology, climate change measures etc.
For those and many more of that kind, countries might face the game theory problem that if they engage in those practices alone, without the other side joining them, they will put a burden upon themselves and run into a disadvantage with respect to those who don't, while if they continue those practices it's equally detrimental for everyone...
So there is a benefit for everyone in not doing it or in doing something else, but there is disadvantage for the 1st one doing so. So if more than 1 country starts it, they at least don't have a disadvantage with respect to each other.
Now the problem with all international law is that you can only enforce it as much as countries let you enforce it. So there are various international agreements that range between signaling intent to binding contracts.
And if they really don't like the law, they can either leave the group or be kicked out of that ... or can be coerced by force, but that's a risky move that might lead to much larger and unregulated hostilities (people usually don't take it well if a bully considers itself outside the law and might act accordingly).
So often enough a lot of the "binding" power of a treaty is in peer pressure and the point that it's more beneficial to be within the group that plays by those rules than it is to be outside of it. For example larger multinational organizations and groups of states, might offer mutual benefits to each other, including development aid for smaller countries, at the price of signing and abiding by those treaties.
Also if basically the entire world had signed a treaty and one country doesn't abide by it, they don't even have to go to war with it. But could just ban that country from international trade, that would already have devastating results and if such punishments are dealt out collectively there's also fewer states that see that as unjustified overreach either.
So ideally a multinational agreement would like to have some "power" behind it, be it numbers (of members), military strength or economic strength, which could make abiding by the law be seen as beneficial and being on the receiving end of such a group as be detrimental.
So if a treaty is signed by the majority of the countries, comprising the majority of the global military and economy, then it can easily apply (effectively) to all, including the non-signatures as these rules might be required de jure or de facto to deal with them and thus become the standard.
A huge problem for that approach though are powerful empires. As they often have the power to deal with other countries outside of the law. Regularly don't feel bound by the law and the collective might neither have the means nor the willingness to kick them out of the group or apply punishment. Because the reverse reason applies here, in that these groups are better off with those countries as members than they are with those countries as adversaries.
So countries like the U.S., Russia, China, etc. routinely not sign treaties or don't consider themselves bound by them with the rest of the world only marginally capable of doing something about it.
Now if the entire world would unite as one and tell them to stick to the rules, they'd probably might still need to do that. For example they often at least pay lip service to these agreements, but if there is no unity and instead block building around superpowers, the power of those treaties over these countries is fairly limited. So in practice they more often apply to smaller countries than larger ones.
Also another problem is that you have to distinguish between individual rule breaking and collective rule breaking by a country. So if companies break rules, is that rule breaking of the country as well? For example for a lack of oversight and can that task be expected to be effectively dealt with by poor countries? How intertwined for example are Chinese companies and the government? How responsible is the U.S. for war crimes committed by mercenaries? Are unmarked Russian soldiers invading Crimea just "people on vacation" or a hostile aggression against a neighboring country?
And even if the situation is crystal clear to see, one might still pretend to buy whatever bullshit the super power might give as explanation if that means that they walk back and reaffirming to abide by the law ... the next time... So yeah international politics can be a lot more complicated.

Yeah, I like the game theory analogy with the choices of going solo, no one doing anything or everyone participating.  The overall idea - of collaboration - is positive, but the devil is very much in the details.  It makes for confusing answers, but it's more realistic than claiming collaboration is always easy and/or well-respected in practice.  +1

Note: this answer is not at all about bilateral treaties, merely multilateral IHL/arms control type of treaties.

On the it-doesn't-matter side...
When it comes to multilateral arms control and/or IHL treaties, I don't know that there are massive advantages to signing.  There is a bit of a stigma to being out of the main treaties, like say the anti-personnel landmine ban treaty.  Or some of Geneva convention ones.  Or the Rome/ICC Treaty.
But I can't think of too many actual hard downsides.  For example:
(this list mostly does not try to differentiate between not signing and signing but not respecting all that much)

Ukraine wasn't in the Rome/ICC treaty, but got its complaints against Russia sponsored by others.

The US did not ban landmines along with most other Western nations.  But it's the US, so it got few downsides from it.  China at UNCLOS arbitration wrt Spratleys?  Lost and royally ignores it.

Israel did not sign some bits of Geneva protocol IV, but really it's still being judged as by others as if it had.  And if there were really no questions about the conduct of the war in Gaza, then them not having signed those bits would not, by itself, bother most of their supporters overmuch (I am sure their adversaries would try to leverage it either way).

Saudi Arabia probably falls short on a number of items, but unless it runs afoul of a dedicated PR campaign against them, like after Khashoggi's murder, it seems to do OK most of the time.

Much of Africa has extremely harsh anti-LGBTQ laws.  That is rarely really a factor in how much aid is/is not given.

Before WW1 - Hague Conventions of 1899 and 1907 - some extremely ambitious and constraining limits were agreed to regarding rules of warfare (submarines warning enemy vessels and picking up survivors, for example).  That went out the window quite quickly.


It's hard to prove a negative.  One place to look would be arms sales that were not allowed by the exporting country due to some unsigned treaty.  Some arms-exporting countries might care, a lot, but most of the bigger ones have a tendency sell to allies or rich customers regardless.
Even then I suspect those mostly fall through - or get waivers - for realpolitik reasons and then the treaty/IHL aspect gets evoked as a justification.
Ditto with aid programs that could be cancelled but rarely are.
An additional reason for some level of cynicism is how much basic human rights get violated throughout the world.  Most of the time that doesn't really result in hard outcomes for the transgressors, not until it gets egregious enough to end up at the ICC.  And since many IHL treaties are signed by many, many, countries the persistence of abuses makes one think that there is quite of lip service going on, with countries signing treaties mostly to avoid looking bad.
For many countries, it really doesn't seem like IHL treaties are that onerous.  They either do it, because they think it's the right thing to do , they actively want to do it, they benefit from participating or it doesn't cost them all that much.  If none of those cases apply, are many overly concerned by compliance, in the absence of strong enforcement mechanisms???  Claims that their own domestic courts will "hold them to account" don't sound all that convincing to me.  It happens, in some countries.  Far from all.  After all, in practice, many countries don't even respect their own lofty constitutions when their governments choose to ignore them.
I would say that the actual practices of a state count for a lot more than the treaties it has signed.
And specifically about the Refugee Conventions, since it's the example asked about.
Non-compliance

An individual may lodge a complaint with the UN Human Rights Committee under the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights or with the UN Committee on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights under the International Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights, but no one has ever done so in regard to violations of the convention. Nations may levy international sanctions against violators, but no nation has ever done so.


At present, the only real consequences of violation are 1) public shaming in the press, and 2) verbal condemnation of the violator by the UN and by other nations. To date, those have not proven to be significant deterrents.

Non-signatories

We find these non-signatory States mostly in the Middle East and in South and Southeast Asia. In the Middle East region, only Iran, Israel, Egypt and Yemen are party to the Convention, while States such as Iraq, Lebanon and Jordan and most States in the Gulf region are non-signatories. Important non-signatory States in South and Southeast Asia include India, Bangladesh, Pakistan, Sri Lanka, Malaysia and Indonesia. In other regions of the world, non-signatory States include Eritrea, Libya, Mongolia and Cuba. Uzbekistan is the only Commonwealth of Independent States country that is not a party to the Convention, while Guyana is the only non-signatory State in South America.

Make of that list what you will, but notice that Lebanon for example is not a signatory, but gets a lot of refugees.  For the rest, some of those countries are generally frowned upon (by the West) for other reasons. But India or Malaysia, for example, are usually well-respected.  And both get a lot of refugees from Myanmar...
But there are still reasons to do it, beyond ethical preferences
(I was, deliberately, cynical in the preceding section.  Truth is, a more collaborative world is a nicer and more efficient world.  The law of the jungle isn't just a zero-sum world, where bigger countries "win" at the cost of lesser ones, it is one where the aggregate wealth and well-being decreases).
Soft power/influence:
The West likes to influence the world by appealing to ethics and the rule of law.  And, for most of our electorates, we at least pretend to care.  Ignoring those treaties, that we have signed and often instigated, comes at the real risk of a loss of soft power.  For example, if the West tries to cajole other countries into containing China, due to claims about Chinese human rights and lack of democracy, but then turns around and ignores/doesn't sign those same treaties, then Chinese diplomats will lose no time pointing that out.
We certainly have seen this scenario play out since the invasion of Ukraine:  most of the "Global South" is following their own self-interests and is quick to point out Western double standards when challenged about it.
"Acceptable warfare treaties"
Most countries have more or less given up the right to use poison gas or biological agents on the battlefield.  Ditto with systems like blinding lasers.  That's certainly been a massive boon to soldiers in war, even if there are occasionally violations:  generally speaking, peer pressure has kept a lid on things.  We haven't seen anything like WW1.
Yes, there is a bit of a free rider issue going on, when a nation doesn't have to be a signatory itself to derive some of the benefits (as you long as they are not in the breach).  But if those treaties were really not signed by enough countries, then the particular methods of war they constrain would not be constrained at all.
To think of it another way:  certain types of weapons bring a lot of misery to their victims, but when employed by both sides, neither side gets much of an "edge" from their use, so little is lost by giving them up and everyone benefits.
And that's before we get into the Geneva convention which still serves as a general benchmark for most states' military behavior on the battlefield.
Absent those types of treaties, war would be even worse than it is.
Trade treaties
The WTO mostly manages to keep a lid on disputes between equal-influence countries, most of the time.  If you believe that trade, while not without drawbacks, has made the world richer overall, then  there is quite a lot of benefit to mutually agreed-upon rules.
Conversely, while trade wars and tariffs can carry a lot of appeal, they can quickly degenerate and impoverish most of those involved, because they are a game that two can play at.  That seems in any case to have been a major factor in how badly the Great Depression played out in 1929.
Global warming
To take a tired metaphor:  imagine you live in a big wooden building with lots of families.  Sure, it's a real drag to have rules about not smoking in apartments.  But you have only one house and if it burns down...
If everybody does their thing, it's going to be "tragedy of the commons" all around.
And one bilateral treaty's abrogation comes as a warning...
p.s. Although I didn't write this about bilateral treaties, I still want to add that there have been real consequences from the USA's 2002 withdrawal from the ABM treaty.  It's hard to prove that Putin wouldn't have become adversarial without that withdrawal, but it certainly didn't help.  Nor should we discount the legitimacy of the concerns that Russia might have had.
Meanwhile, the premises of an effective large-scale anti-ICBM shield are as elusive as ever.  And, arguably, if it did work, it could destabilize MAD deterrence quite a bit.
The world is probably not much safer from that move, no.  Thank so you very much Mssrs. Bush, Cheney & Rumsfeld.  So even top dogs like the US do not always benefit from tearing up the rulebook.  Add China to the mix and a bit more collaborative approach (all around, cuz Xi is hardly a cuddly bear) seems like a good idea.
